# Inserting string in linked list ends up in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to create a linked-list with a string as the value inside each node, but every time I try to call the function that's supposed to add something to the list, it ends up giving me a segmentation fault error.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string data;
    struct node *next;
}*head,*var,*trav;

void add(string value)
{
      struct node *temp; 
      temp=head;
      var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
      var->data =  value;
      if(head==NULL)
      {
          head=var;
          head->next=NULL;
      }
      else
      {
          while(temp->next!=NULL)
          {     
               temp=temp->next;
          }
          var->next=NULL;
          temp->next=var;
      }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    add("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the problem is in the `var->data = value;`, but what exactly is causing it? And how could I fix that?

This is the error that shows up:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: 13056 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

Comment: this is c++ - you should be using `std::list`, or at the very least, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Please do never 'malloc' a structure holding C++ data members!

Comment: that's for data structures class can't use list,but thanks for the help :D

Comment: You are in a Data Structures class and they want you to write a linked list like this?

Comment: They said I can write anyway I want as long as it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc()` does not call the constructor of the `std::string data`, it's just a C function which allocates a chunk memory of specified size and the contents is random junk.

Therefore when you subsequently assign to the string, it does not just set the value like a plain variable does -- it calls function `std::string::operator=`, which tries to release any previous contents first, but that's not correct and it crashes.

You need to use C++ operator `new` to create the node instead, like so:

```
var = new node;
```

As you can see, you also don't need the ugly casts anymore.

Comment: This does not matter in his case - he sets all the fields of the `var` before using them.

Comment: It does -- `var->data =  value;` invokes `std::string::operator=`, which sees e.g. `0xdeadbeef` as its buffer pointer and calls `delete[]` on it -> crash.

Comment: @mark It does - the string in the node will not get constructed using 'malloc'

Comment: Oh, I missed that data was a C++ object.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you forgot to initialize head to NULL

Comment: Global/static variables are always initialized to zeroes.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it was only for the static.

Comment: Yes -- "plain" globals also have "static storage duration", even though they don't have "static scope". Also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3553682/3543211