# How can we be sure that value of 'b' is 0 at beginning in this code

Tags: c, global, pi

This is a program which I came across on the net that calculates the value of .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long a=10000,b,c=2800,d,e,f[2801],g;//--------HERE the value of b---------//

int main()
{
    printf("\nValue of b: %ld", b);
    getch();
    for(;b-c;)
        f[b++]=a/5;
    for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a)
        for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);
}
```

The calculated value is correct. But how could the programmer be sure that the initial value of `b` would be `0`?

It does not seem to be initialized at all!

Is there some specialty about initial value of global variables?

Comment: Global variables are initialized to zero by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553559/how-are-local-and-global-variables-initialized-by-default) question, global variables are initialized to `0` by default.

In your code, `b` is declared as a global variable.